# Websocket connection ssl problem on startup (Windows)

Tags: windows, ssl, websocket, openssl

We have a program called server.exe which starts a websocket server (ws, wss) on computer of client.
It`s main purpose accept connections from browser (127.0.0.1) and send some data to it. It uses openssl dlls (1.0.2.20).
Problem: After startup of Windows server.exe does not work. It does not accept secure connections.
Debug Log with errors:

`10.12.2019_16:11:09:0861 <<< ID = 728, msg: SSL library error during handshake on fd = 728 error:1408A0C1:SSL routines:ssl3_get_client_hello:no shared cipher
10.12.2019_16:11:09:0876 <<< ID = 592, msg: SSL library error during handshake on fd = 592 error:1408A10B:SSL routines:ssl3_get_client_hello:wrong version number
10.12.2019_16:11:09:0876 <<< ID = 776, msg: SSL library error during handshake on fd = 776 error:1408A10B:SSL routines:ssl3_get_client_hello:wrong version number`

But!! If we just restart server.exe - everything begin to work fine!
if we launch server.exe with .bat file (5 sec dealy) - everything is working!
Why? How can we solve problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed. 
server.exe file cannot find path to the dll.